# How to display BigDecimal number with trailing zero in a JSON (not as string)?

Tags: java, json, jackson

In my representation response I have one field which is of BigDecimal type.
Its value is 2.30 but the json response display it as 2.3
Is there any way to show also the trailing zero , without displaying it as a string ? 
BTW - I'm using Jackson library.

```
{
  "version" : 2.3 (needs to be 2.30)
}
```

Comment: There is no difference between the numbers "2.3" and "2.30", as strings they would be different, but as numbers they are not.

Comment: Only string can be used in this case. You can convert `BigDecimal` to `String` just before you create json.

Comment: A version is not a number. _2.30_ is major=:2, minor=30. So this is not a numeric value at all. A simple example is from [jackson repo](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core), a version is in most cases using 3numbers separated by `.` like _1.2.3_

Comment: @AxelH - let's say the field is another thing which is numeric

Comment: Then you don't care, a decimal _.30_ or _.3_ are equivalent, it is still _3/10_. But in the version case; a minor of 3 is different than a minor of 30. If you want to keep the format like this, use a `String` because this is a formatted value.

Comment: Ok, mathematically is correct,  but for my clients it matters.

Comment: Then on the client side, format the number with 2 decimals... (format will be in `String` by the way...); `String.format("%.2f", 2.3);` > `"2.30"`

Answer (score 6):

If you want to keep the JSON holding a numeric value, you don't have the choice, a numeric isn't impacted by the traling "0" in a decimal part, so they won't be used. Simply because :

```
2.3 = 2.30
2.3 = 2.300000
```

The zeros are simply ignored. If you really need to get a value like 2.30, you have two choices,

1. use a `String` to hold the **formatted** number in the JSON
2. format the value on the client side.

Both solution will used the same logic :

```
String.format("%.2f", 2.3); //String: 2.30
```

The difference is the moment you format the value.

## Note:

Since you have a "version" field, I would use a `String` since a version is represented by numeric value separated by `.`. See the maven repo of Jackson :

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.4</version>
</dependency>
```

**2.9.4** is not a number.

Comment: If I will change the BigDecimal to Float / Double , will I be able to do so ?

Comment: No, you could even get worst result with a decimal `2.3` represented by `2.2222222229` because of the floating point "lack" of precision. The problem simply come from the JSON using a numeric value, not a text. PS: if your clients don't understand that `2.3` is the same as `2.30`, then you probably didn't understand their requirements ;).

Comment: I am dealing with legacy code. I can't break the contract.

Comment: Ok @sharon,. With the second solution, you don't have to change anything on the JSON. You send `2.3` and the client will simply format the value as `2.30`. If you really want to do it in the JSON, I will need to check with Jackson to provide the formatter... it is allow in the RFC so it is possible, not sure in Jackson... can you provide a quick [mcve] to build the JSON ? It would be simpler for you to understand.

Answer (score 3):

As others have pointed out, you should really be passing a string in this case to preserve the formatting, since number types in JSON are intended to be pure values.

However, if you really need to do this (output trailing zero's on a number type in JSON generated by Jackson), this is how you do it:

Create a custom serializer class like so:

```
final class PaddedSerializer extends JsonSerializer<BigDecimal> {
      @Override
      public void serialize(BigDecimal value, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider) 
        throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
          jgen.writeRawValue(value.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP).toString());
      }
    }
```

Then on the variable in your binding class that corresponds to the value in question, place the @JsonSerialize annotation to tell it to use your custom serializer class on just that variable:

```
@JsonProperty(required = true)
@JsonSerialize(using = PaddedSerializer.class)
protected BigDecimal version;
```

Comment: The solution you described will still drop trailing zeros. It's simpy json spec that you can't avoid, it's up to the client/receiver to display it in desired format.

Comment: The above solution still leads to the drop of trailing zeroes as the commenter stated.